# Use external system (with OpenId Connect) to provide a second factor of authentication in Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a following scenario. I have some parts of an application which requires higher level of security. I want to have an easy login (let's say sms verification) to most of the app and more secure login with external provider (having Substantial level of assurance according to eIDAS) for the security related stuff. This external provider is connected using OpenId connect.

Requiring to have a two steps login for some parts of the app can be achieved with conditional policies. The question is:
Can we set up custom policy in a way have an OTP a SMS code first and then if conditional access policy will decide there would be the social login connected with OpenId connect? Is that possible in Azure B2C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

It's possible to have a custom policy authenticate a user with OTP via SMS then optionally have a social login occur via OpenID Connect. However, it's not possible to set up a conditional access policy (in Entra/Azure AD B2C) that will provide a recommendation to perform a social login.

Azure AD B2C conditional access policies will only provide recommendations that a user should perform MFA, be blocked, require password change (in certain circumstances), or have no action applied. So, your "conditional access policy" would have to be something that's defined outside of Azure AD B2C and called as part of the custom policy.

For example, you could pass value into the B2C /authorize request and only trigger the social login when that value is present, or you could call a REST API and have the response dictate whether to trigger the social login.